# How can I upload my asp.net web services to a host online?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I created a web application which uses a web service, this web-service itself utilizes another web-service and they all work well on local host (and Visual Studio 2010 of course!).

Now I need to test them on my live website but I have no idea how I can deploy the web-services! The fact that one of them references the other one even gets me more confused. I am not using WCF services, these are traditional asp.net web-services (under .netframewrok 3.5).

How can I get this online?  I have uploaded my web-service [here](http://www.mendez.somee.com/MailUitiltyService/MailUtility.asmx), but it gives me errors, I don't know if I am doing it right!

Comment: Can you please paste the error here.

Comment: I think @mac has given some good advice.. But this might be a straight up deployment issue rather than a web service deployment issue.. Can you get a simple hello world type page to show up in your deployment environment ? If so than macs answer is probably correct.

Comment: Thank you guys, I could finally get around this and get them to work. My Problem was that i needed to convert my folder to an application i did that and they started to work just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First thing that should be done is to copy the Folder containing your `Web-Service` files onto your host (e.g by `FileZilla` or any other means of transferring files ).
When you are done, If you are on some web hosting plans such as `somee.com`,  You need to
convert the uploaded folder to an Application.
When you do so, you should be able to access your `Web-Service` file (pointing to the .asmx file (e.g MyWebService.asmx ))
Use this URL in your project (be it another `WebService` or `Web Application` or `Windows Form Aplication` or what ever ) 
When you are done, You can apply the same method, you have just done to other projects (Web-services , web applications , etc). They should work fine.
By the way, One can also publish a WebService as `Dll` and use them in what ever project them deem to fit.
If you have problem with deployment mentioned above you can use this method to use your webservice.
For this to happen, When you are in your WebService Project, Go to Build menu choose Publish and use FileSystem from the drop down menu and the rest is self explanatory :)

Answer (score 1):

if i am not wrong you need a web reference of your live Domain web service.

Just include the web reference of live web service into your local development

update the calling method like

localhost.websericemethodName() to your liveWeb.websericemethodName() and upload your code on your live development.

side by side update your web.config file of your live domain to include the updated web service reference and also upload your web reference files to your live domain.

Comment: i have uploaded my webservice here: http://www.mendez.somee.com/MailUitiltyService/MailUtility.asmx   
but it gives me errors, i dont know if i am doing it right!